# Loop through rows of a dataframe based on value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe that I am trying to represent visually. I am struggling to figure out the y-positions (labelled in this df as level)

The data frame looks like, and I am trying to fill in the level column to show it as 1 higher than the line managers level (NOT GRADE):

```
name        manager    grade   manager_grade   level
Michael    -           1       -               1
Jim        Michael     2       1               2      
Dwight     Michael     2       1               2
Darryl     Michael     3       1               2
Angela     Michael     3       1               2
Pam        Michael     4       1               2
Roy        Darryl      4       3               3
Kevin      Angela      4       3               3
```

I know this will require the table to be sorted by grade, and then the level needs to be iteratively calculated by a for loop.

This is what I have so far:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df[manager_grade][i] is None:
       df['level'][i] = df['grade'][i]
    else:
       df['level][i] = df['manager_grade'][i]+ 1
```

However, that just adds 1 to the manager grade, not the level of their manager. Does anyone know how I can amend the above code to reflect the level of the manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`networkx`](https://networkx.org) and [`bfs_layer`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_layers.html) to identify the different layers (ranks) of nodes:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                           source='manager', target='name')
G.remove_node('-')

# get roots
roots = {n for n, d in G.in_degree() if d==0}
# {'Michael'}

# map rank from BFS layer
mapper = {n: i for i, l in
          enumerate(nx.bfs_layers(G, roots), start=1)
          for n in l}

df['level'] = df['name'].map(mapper)
```

Output:

```
      name  manager  grade manager_grade  level
0  Michael        -      1             -      1
1      Jim  Michael      2             1      2
2   Dwight  Michael      2             1      2
3   Darryl  Michael      3             1      2
4   Angela  Michael      3             1      2
5      Pam  Michael      4             1      2
6      Roy   Darryl      4             3      3
7    Kevin   Angela      4             3      3
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: This worked amazingly! Would it be possible to use networkx to find the xpos as well?

Comment: what is `xpos`?

Comment: Sorry, i meant the x position!

Comment: @ds_1234 sorry but it's still unclear, you have `grade` and `manager_grade`, are you referring to one of those?

Comment: No I mean the x position of each of the nodes in the visualisation.

Comment: If you mean in the shown graph, this depends on the layout that is used. You generally don't compute this yourself. If you mean the position in the layer, (Michael=0, Jim=0, Dwight=1, …, Pam=4, Roy=0, Kevin=1), then you can use a second `enumerate` on `l` in the dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I completely missed it, I think this is a graph problem :

```
#pip install networkx
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df, source="name", target="manager", create_using=nx.DiGraph
)

df["level"] = df["name"].map(lambda n: len(nx.descendants(G, n)))
```

Output :

```
print(df)

      name  manager  grade manager_grade  level
0  Michael        -      1             -      1
1      Jim  Michael      2             1      2
2   Dwight  Michael      2             1      2
3   Darryl  Michael      3             1      2
4   Angela  Michael      3             1      2
5      Pam  Michael      4             1      2
6      Roy   Darryl      4             3      3
7    Kevin   Angela      4             3      3
```

Comment: I think networkx/graph theory is the solution, but computing all descendents just to get the level might be inefficient

Comment: Thanks mozway ;), I wasn't confident at first. Regarding efficiency, I'll take note of that because I'm just starting with the graph theory.